# [Ruby on rails]How to maintain URL params trough different controller views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an app that allows the tracking of different types of contracts and I was tasked with making a multiple filtering functionality, however, as the user moves between views, his criteria is suppose to maintain so when they come back to the main view they don't have to input it again, passing them trough every link is not feasible and it simply won't work since i'm restricting the search params.

At first i thought overwriting the default_url_options options method was a good enough solution but this creates more problems than it solves since now the params are very sticky and hard to get rid off

So, what is the better way to maintain this params trough the different views of the controller?

My code:

```
class ContractsController < ApplicationController
....
private

 def search_params
  params.permit(:contractor_id,  :starting_date, 
  :ending_date, :state, :proccess_number).delete_if 
  {|key, value| value.blank? }
 end

 def default_url_options (options={})
  search_params
 end 
 ....
end
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider storing these variables in the user's session. That way you're not relying on resubmitting the parameters between views.

That way you could do:

```
session[:contractor_id] = params[:contractor_id]
session[:starting_date] = params[:starting_date]
```

And in a different action you can retrieve it:

```
session[:contractor_id]
session[:starting_date]
```

Comment: Just tried it and worked really well! however instead of making a session variable for each param I just created one that contains the whole params hash so I could have an easier time manipulating it.